# Jest - how can i run only tests within specific matching subfolders?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am breaking up my tests into subfolders to represent what "type" of tests they are, like unit tests, or integration tests

how can i configure `jest` in my CLI command to run tests in subfolders matching `src/**/__unit__/**/*.spec.ts`?

- needs to be within /src folder in the root of project directory
- **unit** can appear in any subfolder of /src

```
PS> npx jest --testRegex "src\**\__unit__\**\*.spec.ts"
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In C:\Users\ALilland\Documents\dev\controlair\scheduler
  75 files checked.
  testMatch:  - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 75 matches
  testRegex: src\**\\__unit__\**\*.spec.ts - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
```

it has to be in the CLI argument, because I will have multiple versions in my `package.json` file representing different types of tests, so i cant add them to the `jest.config.js` file

Answer (score 0):

The [`testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring) configuration can do this.

E.g.

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/stackoverflow/75262784/src/**/__unit__/**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)'],
};
```

Folder structure:

```bash
☁  jest-v26-codelab [main] ⚡  tree -L 4 stackoverflow/75262784
stackoverflow/75262784
└── src
    ├── client
    │   └── index.test.ts
    └── server
        ├── __integration__
        │   └── index.test.ts
        └── __unit__
            └── index.test.ts

5 directories, 3 files
```

Run `jest` command, test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75262784/src/server/__unit__/index.test.ts
  75262784 - server unit
    ✓ should pass (2 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.642 s, estimated 9 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have roots like this

apps/folder1/.../

apps/folder2/.../

then you can run all test from folder1 like this.

```
jest apps/foldeer1/**
```

then in your **jest.config.json**

```
{
...
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "roots": [
    ...,
    "<rootDir>/apps/",
    ...
  ],
...
}
```

Comment: sorry, this isnt what im asking -- `__unit__` folders can appear in any number of nested folders within `/src`